# How to observe a turtle if it is not moving at that time instant ? (Netlogo)

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

in my model pedestrians are turtles so I want to observe when do they move and when they do not.i have given them property that if patch-ahead is not empty and they are not finding any empty patch in the cone 1 120, they will not move.so i want to observe their motion.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide some context. Either edit your question to clarify your question or if possible provide some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: Those people downvoting the question or upvoting the clarification request, please don't do so unless you know NetLogo. This question is a lot clearer than it looks as many of the terms used are defined in the NetLogo language.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to focus attention on the turtle that is moving is to either change colour or size, or you can print out the something when the turtle moves. Something like this:

```
ask turtles
[ ifelse patch-ahead not any? turtles-on [patch-set patch-ahead 1 patches in-cone 1 120]
  [ set color red
    forward 1
  ]
  [ set color blue
  ]
]
```